# What type of revolver gun used by the Joker that shoots more than 6 bullets?

Tags: plot-explanation, joker

In *Joker (2019)* while the Joker character was assaulted by the 3 men in the train/subway, he pulls out the revolver gun and shoots and kills the men. Some of them are shot 2 or 3 times.

We don't see the Joker reloading the gun at any point, but I counted at least 8 bullets fired.

Was this a mistake?
[image: Joker Subway gun scene]

Comment: There are a lot of discussions about the „unreliable narrator“ Arthur in that movie. Many people see this little detail as a hint that a lot of things that happen in the movie are simply not real and only exist in the mind of Arthur...

So this was probably not an error but intended by the film makers. I don‘t know if this holds true for that specific scene, but it Fits that theory quite well.

You can read all about this in [this duplicate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104622/how-does-arthur-manage-to-fire-eight-bullets) of your question. I would Vtc, but do not enough rep.

Comment: The [script](https://d2bu9v0mnky9ur.cloudfront.net/academy2019/screenplay/joker/joker_new_final.pdf) has him firing seven rounds. Not an uncommon number of shots for a ***".38 snub-nosed revolver"***

Answer (score 3):

[IMFDB](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Joker_(2019)) has pegged this down as a [Smith & Wesson Chief's Special](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson_Model_36#Smith_.26_Wesson_Model_36_.22Chiefs_Special.22) which apparently holds only 5 rounds (I do not know anything about weapons, except that such as thing as the Internet Movies Firearms Database does exist), so this is an error (albeit a pretty common one in movies).

Comment: For what it's worth there do exist revolvers that can hold 8 rounds. But, you're right about the chief's special which is certainly the one used here.

Comment: My revolver holds nine!  The caliber is .22 but still it counts ;P

Comment: @AntonSherwood, Ian Mccollum (of forgottenweapons.com) has a video about a revolver that holds twenty rounds (an antique that uses percussion caps, but it still counts, right ?) :-)